# Search title from input tag by classname and action

Tags: search, input, tags, title, classname

I want to get the title called "ABCD" as output from below :
Note I can't use input id to search and have to use classname. Also, note that I have several  `<div class="promptChoiceListBox" >` and `class="promptTextField promptTextFieldReadOnly"` exist and this is just one example.

Also this Title is dynamic and changed with dropdown selection. 
How can I check it in onclick event if the text inside the text is changed?

How can I achieve this ? any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="promptChoiceListBox" >
<input id="xyz123" type="text" class="promptTextField promptTextFieldReadOnly" readonly="" title="ABCD">
```

I have tried below and it doesn't work:

```
console.log($('.promptTextField').attr('title'));
```

thanks

Comment: console.log($('.promptTextField')) should give you a LIST?

Comment: @Anona112 : it gives me all input ID list and not the title which I want

Answer (score 0):

Javascript way of doing it:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("xyz123").title);
```

JQuery (on-click example):

```
$("input:promptTextField promptTextFieldReadOnly").click(function(){
    $("input:promptTextField promptTextFieldReadOnly").toggle();
});
```

Comment: I have array of elements and not single item . So your javascript solution is fine with 1 elements . Also how can I trigger the onlcikc change of title elements ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.promptTextField').map(x=>x.title)
```